# How different material capacitors can develop different charges?

Tags: charge, potential-energy, capacitance, conductors, batteries

I learned in a video tutorial that same battery could produce different charges based upon different capacitance of the materials used.

Also A capacitor fully charged has the same voltage as the battery.

Now if both capacitors separated by same distance but made of different material, are charged by same battery. So the capactior must develop same voltage, then shouldn’t they have same charge? As

[image]

Comment: Answer in denominator of voltage expression, permitivitty of material. More the permitivitty more the capacitance or charge.

Comment: @NeilLibertine sir, isn't permittivity related to the medium rather than material containing the charge

Answer (score 0):

You have quoted an incorrect formula.
Your formula is the potential $V$ at a distance $r$ from a point charge $Q$ in a medium of permittivity $\epsilon$, not $E$ as that is usually reserved for electric field (strength).

The capacitance $C\,\left(= \frac QV=\frac{\text{charge stored on plates}}{\text{voltage across plates}}\right)$  of a parallel plate capacitor of area $A$, plate separation $d$ and permittivity $\epsilon$ is $C=\dfrac {\epsilon A}{d}$.

The permittivity is a property of the material (dielectric) between the plates and has a different value for different materials.

The permittivity can be written in terms of the relative permittivity (or [dielectric constant](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/liquid-dielectric-constants-d_1263.html)) $\epsilon_{\rm r}$ and the permittivity of a vacuum $\epsilon _{\rm 0}$ as $\epsilon = \epsilon_{\rm r}\,\epsilon _{\rm 0}$.

So different materials between the plates of a capacitor will result in different values of capacitance and hence for the same voltage across the plates, differing amounts of charge stored.

Comment: Sir, I know, C = Q/V and C is different for different materials. And that is what I am struggling to understand as how could C be different for different material conductor when they develop same voltage on connecting to same battery.
I mean you take two capacitor one lets say made of copper, another made of iron. 
Now as it is said in tutorial, any conductor will develop same voltage as the battery on fully charging.
So, both capacitor will develop same potential, and hence they must have same charge. And if they same charge then how could capacitance be different for different materials?

Comment: @DhaneshKhurana As long as they are conductors the material of the capacitor plates does not affect the capacitance.